# Colored ghci output on PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, haskell, exec, ghci

Some time ago, I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/rhysd/ghci-color/raw/master/ghci-color). However, since I'm using Windows, I'm unable to run it. Hence, I decided to create a `.ps1` version of it so I would be able to run it in PowerShell. However I've been getting the following error:

```
Line |
  25 |  Invoke-Expression (Get-Command ghci).Path $args 2>&1 | `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
```

My complete code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/P0Y6EdYu) and the specific part where the error lies is as follows:

```
Invoke-Expression (Get-Command ghci).Path $args 2>&1 | `
    sed "$load_failed `
         $load_done `
         $no_instance `
         $interactive `
         $double_colon ` 
         $right_arrow `
         $right_arrow2 `
         $parenthesis ` 
         $left_blacket `
         $right_blacket `
         $double_colon `
         $calc_operators `
         $string `
         $char"
```

Also, the original code I'm trying to convert, written in shell script(.sh), is as follows

```sh
exec "`which ghc`" --interactive ${1+"$@"} 2>&1 |\
    sed "$load_failed\
         $load_done\
         $no_instance\
         $interactive\
         $double_colon\
         $right_arrow\
         $right_arrow2\
         $parenthesis\
         $left_blacket\
         $right_blacket\
         $double_colon\
         $calc_operators\
         $string\
         $char"
```

And I'd like to clarify that I have installed `sed` on my PowerShell. Thank you in advance.

### `Update`

I've managed to resolve the earlier mentioned error thanks to [@Mike Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906991/colored-ghci-output-on-powershell#answer-71912680)'s suggestion to use `@args` instead of `$args`. However, I seem to be getting another error as shown below:

```
sed: 13: "s/^Failed, modules load ...": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

Apparently there seems to be an error with the following part of my code:

```
$load_failed="s/^Failed, modules loaded:/$RED&$RESET/;"
$load_done="s/done./$GREEN&$RESET/g;"
$double_colon="s/::/$PURPLE&$RESET/g;"
$right_arrow="s/\->/$PURPLE&$RESET/g;"
$right_arrow2="s/=>/$PURPLE&$RESET/g;"
$calc_operators="s/[+\-\/*]/$PURPLE&$RESET/g;"
$char="s/'\\?.'/$RED&$RESET/g;"
$string="s/`"[^`"]*`"/$RED&$RESET/g;"
$parenthesis="s/[{}()]/$BLUE&$RESET/g;"
$left_blacket="s/\[\([^09]\)/$BLUE[$RESET\1/g;"
$right_blacket="s/\]/$BLUE&$RESET/g;"
$no_instance="s/^\s*No instance/$RED&$RESET/g;"
$interactive="s/^<[^>]*>/$RED&$RESET/g;"
```

and more specifically:

```
$string="s/`"[^`"]*`"/$RED&$RESET/g;"
```

The original code written in shell script reads:

```
string="s/\"[^\"]*\"/$RED&$RESET/g;"
```

I'm really confused where the unbalanced brackets are so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [1] get rid of the  backticks after pipes. they are not needed. ///// [2] get rid of the other backticks by using splatting. >>> `Get-Help about_Splatting` <<< ///// [3] where are all the `$load_failed` and other such $vars coming from?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you for your input. I've actually defined all the variables above [here](https://pastebin.com/P0Y6EdYu).

Comment: you are welcome! ///// the error SEEMS to be saying that the `$Args` variable is not being accepted. it looks like your `I-E` call is wrong. this >>> `Invoke-Expression [-Command] <System.String> [<CommonParameters>]` <<< seems to say that there is supposed to be just one string in the `-Command` parameter ... and you have two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are two layers of escaping going on.

Try:

```
$string="s/`"[^\`"]*`"/$CYAN&$RESET/g;"
```

Instead of:

```
$string="s/`"[^`"]*`"/$RED&$RESET/g;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need Invoke-Expression at all, just use ghci as if you would on the command line e.g. (assuming ghc is added to your PATH variable)

```
$ret = ghci @args
```